# Should I check the state of objects returned by methods I am testing

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests for my service layer. I have a method named `placeOrder` that returns an `Order` object. I have a  unit-test that checks that the returned `Order` object is not null.

Should I also check the state of the returned object to ensure that the `placeOrder` method has set it correctly? For example, checking the order date, number of order lines, the user that placed it.

Or is my check that the returned object is not null enough?

Comment: I imagine that somewhere you'd need to check that the right orders are being produced. That may be achieved by testing the returned object, or they may be other approaches. Hard to advise on a broad, general question like this.

Comment: It might be helpful if you gave us some context,/other validation/what are you doing with the object. there's quite a lot of possible answers here

Answer (score 0):

I use a [programming-by-contract](/questions/tagged/programming-by-contract) approach to produce my code. If I am testing a method, my test cases check *all* the post-conditions (including the invariants) of the method that can be expressed reasonably simply in terms of the arguments to the method, the state of the object before the method call and the state of the object after the method call.

Why? Because I can not predict *which* post-condition or invariant might be broken by an incorrect refactoring or enhancement, so I must test them all, or nearly all of them.

Conversely, if the field of a returned object is not part of a post-condition, I tend not to check its value in tests, *unless* I know I must check it to ensure correct operation of the method. And how do I know which fields those are? I also use a [tdd](/questions/tagged/tdd) approach; if the *minimum required change* to code under development to make it pass the existing set of tests is to not both setting some field values, I deliberately refrain from setting those fields, and add to my TODO list a test-case (or cases) that check that *those* fields are correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it depends on what the method's purpose is - to populate the object's members or just to return an already populated (from somewhere else) object.

Let's say your method does this:

```
public Order placeOrder() {
    Order order = new Order();
    order.setUser("John Smith");
    //more members are set...
    return order;
}
```

In this case, obviously, the methods purpose is to populate the `order`'s members and then to return the object. In this case your unit test has to **ensure** that the returned object has (all) it's members populated, e.g.

```
@Test
public void testPlaceOrder() {
    Order order = myServiceInstance.placeOrder();
    assertNotNull(order);
    assertNotNull(order.getUser());
    //more assertions
}
```

---

The other case is the one in which your `placeOrder` method **just** returns an already populated object. For example:

```
public Order placeOrder(Order order) {
    someExternalMethodThatPopulatesTheOrder(order);
    return order;
}
```

In this case, your unit-test should just test the functionality of the `placeOrder` method and should not case if the `someExternalMethodThatPopulatesTheOrder()` *works correctly*. Given this, you can **mock** the `someExternalMethodThatPopulatesTheOrder()`'s functionality (with libraries like PowerMock or Mockito), so that you can test the functional purpose of your `placeOrder` method.